# for loop doesn't iterate through the lines of a text file

Tags: windows, printing, batch-file, for-loop, command-prompt

I have a for loop that is supposed to print each line of a text file. Instead it's printing the `logPath`.
This is the code:

```
  set enabledelayedexpansion

  for %%G in (C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\*.properties) DO (
      Set fileName=%%~nxG
       ...
     set logPath="C:/ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2/Logs/!fileName!.log"
       ...         
        For /f "tokens=*" %%B in (!logPath!) Do (
      echo Inside the for loop for printing each line!!
      set logLine=%%B
      print !logLine!  REM this prints the logPath instead of each logLine and jumps out of this for loop after the 1st iteration!
     )
 )
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo off
For %%G in (C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\*.properties) DO (      
      FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in (%%G) do @echo %%i 
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't tell us which line is issuing the "invalid switch" error message, but I see several potential problems:

1. to use `!variables!` you need to **enable delayed expansion**

   ```
   SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   ```
2. don't use `'/'` in filenames, change to `'\'`

   ```
   set logPath="C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\Logs\!fileName!.log"
   ```
3. `print` command sends a text file to the printer. Change it to `echo`

   ```
   echo !logLine!
   ```

Comment: You are right that the Windows API can accept either the backslash or slash but the convention is to use a backslash, and microsoft APIs that return paths use backslashes. And many programs and libraries don't accept slashes. So, I have edited the answer to state *potential* problems, as we don't know what other programs run in SO's BAT file.

Comment: The question is: do these slashes cause the error. And I don't think so.

Comment: I don't, neither. But we can't be sure, as we don't know what those lines with ... do. Using slashes in filenames on Windows is a potential source of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use backslashes instead of forward slashes.

```
set "logPath=C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\Logs\!fileName!.log"
```

While usually you can use them interchangeably in Windows, `cmd` is a special case as the forward slash is used for switches and options to built-in commands. And its parser often stumbles over forward slashes. You usually can safely pass such paths to external commands, though.

Comment: I was just adding another guess. From what they wrote no one can really figure out what's wrong, anyway ;-)